# Solidity Mapping, values are same for different users

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, remix

I'm coming from Java background and trying to learn Solidity,but stuck with mapping. Idea was to have simple balance that i can reduce or increment. But the problem is that when i enter some address and add value ,it's added but when i enter another address same balance is saved.It should be a zero because nothing is added yet.

```
    
  contract ContractTest{
    
    int totalDeposit;
   
    constructor() public{
      totalDeposit = 0;
    }

    struct User{ 
      int total;
    }

    mapping(address => User) public users;

    function addBalance(int amt) public{
      totalDeposit = totalDeposit + amt;
      users [msg.sender] = User(totalDeposit);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: My be ```users [msg.sender].total += amt;``` ?

Comment: Yup that was a problem, how i haven't figure it :D